# Multivariate Bernoulli, Covariances for Categorical Data

Tags: distributions, estimation, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, binary-data

I need to find outliers in multidimensional, categorical, 1-hot encoded, binary data. Data might look like,

```
0,1,1,0
1,1,0,0
1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1
0,0,1,0
```

I toyed with the idea of representing this data as multivariate bernoulli. My hope was that it could represent the frequency of the 1's as well as  their dependencies, through empirical covariance, somehow.

A section in book Fundamentals of Data Mining Algorithms pg 83 seemed to just that, however the joint PMF it specifies,

$$
P \big(\textbf{X} = (e_{1i},e_{2j})\big) = 
f(e_{1i},e_{2i}) = 
p_{ij} \prod_{r=1}^{m_1} \prod_{s=1}^{m_2} p_{ij}^{e_{ir}^1 \cdot e_{js}^12}
$$

did not seem right (the $e$'s are standard basis vectors, the details can be found in the book).

I have two questions:

1) There doesn't seem to be any covariances in this PMF, the author talks about sample mean and covariance later in the section, but it does not connect with the PMF. I expected a distribution akin to a multivariate normal which has covariance matrix built right into it.

2) Can't I use something simple to achieve what I am trying to do? I cooked up a simple solution using cooccurences, using this I can get something that comes close to a distribution. Example (in Python)

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([\
[0,1,1,0],
[1,1,0,0],
[1,1,1,0],
[0,1,1,1],
[0,0,1,0]
])
c = A.T.dot(A) / float(len(A))
print c
```

The result

```
[[ 0.4  0.4  0.2  0. ]
 [ 0.4  0.8  0.6  0.2]
 [ 0.2  0.6  0.8  0.2]
 [ 0.   0.2  0.2  0.2]]
```

Then for new data,

```
vec = np.array([[0,1,1,0]])
tmp = vec.T.dot(vec); print tmp
d = np.diag(vec[0])
print np.dot(np.dot(d, c), d)
print np.dot(np.dot(d, c), d).sum()
```

Output

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
[ 0.8  0.6  0.6  0.8]
2.8
```

I calculate cooccurence (multiply transpose of $A$ with itself). This gives me how many times each binary column occurs with another, the independent frequency is in the diagonal. I normalize this and I get a matrix that can be used as a distribution. For new data I do the same thing -- multiply transpose of vector with itself, but this time use the result (which only has 1's in it) as a "filter" -- through diag, and two dot products, that pulls out only the parts of the cooccurence matrix I am interested in. Then I sum the result.

The new vector above gave a high "score", 2.8, as seen above. Another one

```
vec = np.array([[1,0,0,1]])
```

would have given 0.6.

Is this usable? Does anyone know a distribution that can represent binary variables in a way multivariate normal can represent real variables? It feels like there should be a distribution for this.